# How to get row data of a html table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="  sorting_1">opps</td>
    <td class="center "> <a href="#" onclick="tst(this)" class="btn btn-warning">
    <i class="icon-edit icon-white">      
    </i> Edit</a>

    </td>
</tr>
```

On click of that hyperlink i need the td values of the row.

This javascript i tried

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#tblTest td:nth-child(2)").click(function (event) {
         //Prevent the hyperlink to perform default behavior
         event.preventDefault();
         var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
         var sr = $td.eq(0).text();
         alert(sr);
     });
 });
```

This one works if i put in Table click event.
I need on click of that hyperlink it should happen.
How to achieve this ?
Thanks in Advance.

without iterating row by row if any method is there to get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding `click` event to `td` bind it to `a`

*Change*

```
$("#tblTest td:nth-child(2)").click(function (event) {
```

*To*

```
$("#tblTest td:nth-child(2) a").click(function (event) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("a.btn").click(function (event) {
    //Prevent the hyperlink to perform default behavior
    event.preventDefault();
    var $td = $(this).parent().closest('tr').children('td');
    var sr = $td.eq(0).text();
    alert(sr);
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rat8e/)

Comment: Its the class name for the link you have, `<a href="#" onclick="tst(this)" class="btn btn-warning">`

Comment: some where i went wrong ? i didn't remove that previous function also.
may be that's reason ?

Comment: Try to remove the `onclick` attribute from the link

Comment: yeah removed and tested same result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28041/discussion-between-raj-and-will-i-am)